# Text Boxes Validations in Jsp

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my Jsp I have two text boxes txt1 and txt2

How can I validate these two text boxes ( txtboxes won't be same...)?

(I need an alert "Both the places are same")

Here is the code:

```
  <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txt1"></asp:TextBox>

        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txt2"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: Do you want to do this on the client (javascript) or on the server (Java)?

Comment: In JavaScript or Jquery...

Comment: BTW: jQuery *IS* JavaScript.

Comment: yes...I need like that..

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you add a cssClass to them. So you have easier time selecting them. Here is an example:

**Mark up**

```
<asp:TextBox CssClass="compare" runat="server" ID="txt1">test</asp:TextBox>    
<asp:TextBox  CssClass="compare"  runat="server" ID="txt2">test</asp:TextBox>
```

**Javascript**

```
var elements = $('.compare');
if (elements.eq(0).html() === elements.eq(1).html()){
   //do stuff
}
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/LE5Br/1/)

Remember this only does client side validation.